# Google script UrlFetch quota does not reset/replenish

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch, quota

I have been having this issue on my multiple Google accounts (all are consumer accounts, not GSuite). Whenever I try to run any requests with use of UrlFetch function I keep getting the error:

```
"Service invoked too many times for one day: urlfetch."
```

I went to [myaccount.google.com/permissions?pli=1](http://myaccount.google.com/permissions?pli=1) and revoked permissions for  all scripts that could use the external services. In fact I shut down ALL access for all the scripts. That was last week!

And yet I still don't have the quota replenished/restored.

I read all that Google Developers website has to read about the quota.

Comment: This looks like an issue to be reported to developers relations (aka customer service) and not a programming issue. I think that you should try the Google Apps Script Issue tracker.

Comment: By the way, are you using consumer accounts or G Suite accounts?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @Rubén, thanks! Google refers to Stackoverflow as the prefered place to seek help. Vicious circle :)

Comment: @halfer, thanks for correcting my grammar. mentioning of urgency was indeed unnecessary, as linguistic errors were a sufficient sign of the rush in finding solution.